# SearchBox windows App 8.1 , searching a substring "contained"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Building an App for windows store 8.1, i implement my searchbox, following the tutorial.
But, it works good only searching a substring that "startWith" another.

If i try to use something like "contains" i got a crush, an unhandled exception.

It works at the first, but if i change the query in the searchBox it crush ... often, not allways.

I can't understand the debugger message,because it refers to the app code...

That's my debugger message

```
Debugger:Debugger Break 
 A break in the debugger session because a user paused the session.
 Time: 13/04/2014 12:34:34
 Thread:<No Name>[6220]
```

and refers to

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
    }
```

my e object got an Exception : incorrect Parameter, handled : false....

that's my SuggestionRequested function, where there is the problem (i think)

```
        public async void OnSuggest(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        TransporterExt tr_search = new TransporterExt();
        ObservableCollection<TransporterExt> querySuggestions = new ObservableCollection<TransporterExt>();
        var queryText = args.QueryText != null ? args.QueryText.Trim() : null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText)) return;

        suggested.Clear();

        tr_search.name = queryText;
        try
        {


            var suggestionCollection = args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;


             querySuggestions = await TransporterService.Search(tr_search);    



            if (querySuggestions != null && querySuggestions.Count > 0 )

             {

                 int i = 0;
                 foreach (TransporterExt tr in querySuggestions)
                 {
                     string strB = sender.QueryText;
                     string strA = tr.name;
                     if(await Utility.Compare(strA,strB))

                     //using this condition all works fine
                     //if (tr.name.StartsWith(sender.QueryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                     {
                         string name = tr.name;
                         string detail = tr.trId.ToString(); 
                         string tag = i.ToString(); 
                         string imageAlternate = "imgDesc";

                         suggestionCollection.AppendResultSuggestion(name, detail, tag, imgRef, imageAlternate);
                         if(tr!=null)
                         suggested.Add(tr);

                         i++;
                     }


               }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //Ignore any exceptions that occur trying to find search suggestions.
             Debug.WriteLine("Exception  " + exc.Message);
             Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

and the Contains utility

```
       public static async Task<bool>Compare(string A, string B) {
        bool contains = Regex.Match(A, B, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
        Debug.WriteLine("regex ="+contains);
        return contains;
    }
```

I got this SearchBox in a UserControl, and that's the code of my UC

```
        public delegate void SuggestionsRequested(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args);

    public event Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<SearchBox, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs> SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested;

    private void SearchBoxSuggestions(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested != null)
            SearchBoxSuggestionsRequested(sender, args);
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("TruckFormUCException");
    }
```

It's possible to search with another logic instead of "startswith"?... where's my fault?

Comment: I'm not sure where your crashing bug is, but you are not calling deferral.Complete() if you code decides to return. This is most definitely a breach of the "contract".

Comment: mmm yes, but i need a not null string. but the problem persist also if a remove that return, the problem persist with a valid string...i can't understand why it works perfectly if i search with the "startsWith" method instead the "contains"